# Notepad++ regex make text url safe and compliant

Tags: notepad++, regex

How to create regex which would to the following:

I have long list of product names and SKU's separated by TAB.

```
Name Nameson[TAB]SKU
Name2 Nameson 2[TAB]SKU2
```

I would need the text to go:

FROM

```
Joey's "Special" Name of the Beverage   ProductNA5434 
Öetkär's Burgér/Pizza   Food123
```

TO

```
joeys-special-name-of-the-beverage-productna5434
oetkars-burger-pizza-food123
```

So the actions are:

1. Replace european regional special characters with safe version for example:

   - `ä,á,å etc` => `a`
   - `ö etc` => `o`
   - `e,é,è etc` => `e`
   - `ú,ù,ü etc` => `u`
   - and so forth.
2. Replace only following symbols: `Spacebar Tab , . / \ _` => `-`
3. Remove more special symbols altogether for example `'´"?!@£$€{[]}` etc.
4. (optional) Make all text lower case

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What about letters from another alphabet than latin?

Comment: I have tried to google for a good bit and study how to create my own regular expressions, but unfortunately this is not my area of expertise and I have been unable to find a good solution or get a good grasp on how to create one.

I dont think I will ever face other alphabet than latin in my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `([àäâ])|([éèëê])|([îï])|([öôò])|([ùûü])|([\h,./-]+)|[^a-z0-9\r\n]+`
- Replace with: `(?1a:(?2e:(?3i:(?4o:(?5u:(?6-))))))`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
([àäâ])             # group 1, letter "a" with diacritics, you can add other if needed
|                   # OR
([éèëê])            # group 2, letter "e" with diacritics, you can add other if needed
|                   # OR
([îï])              # group 3, letter "i" with diacritics, you can add other if needed
|                   # OR
([öôò])             # group 4, letter "o" with diacritics, you can add other if needed
|                   # OR
([ùûü])             # group 5, letter "u" with diacritics, you can add other if needed
|                   # OR
([\h,./-]+)         # group 6, spaces, comma ...
|                   # OR
[^a-z0-9\r\n]+      # any character that is not letter, digit or linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists (i.e; found à, â, ä, ...)
  a           # replace with a
:           # else
  (?2         # if group 2 exists
    e           # replace with e
  :           # else
    (?3         # if group 3 exists
      i           # replace with i
    :           # else
      (?4         # if group 4 exists
        o           # replace with o
      :           # else
        (?5         # if group 5 exists
          u           # replace with u
        :           # else
          (?6         # if group 6 exists
            -           # replace with -
))))))      # endifs
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

---

To lowercase the whole text:

1. Select all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

Comment: THIS WORKS! How can I ever thank you enough. You just made my day, week and even the year! Thank you, thank you, thank you so much Toto!

Comment: @Nolf: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)